# Hashes using min and max

Tags: ruby

Trying to putout the cheapest and the most expensive product. but its not working like i hoped its putting out 3.99 for min and max its putting out 1.89. I'm stumped I've tried min and max I've tried to google but I'm not coming up with anything.

```
This part is the products.txt

    767,POP,1.89
    341,CANDY,3.99
    587,PIZZA,12.99
    453,energy drink,4.00
```

```
    hash = {}
files = File.open("products.txt", "r")

files.each_line do |line|
  id, name, price = line.chomp.split(',')
  hash[id] = [name, price]
end

files.close

while true
  print "\n5. View highest-priced product and lowest-priced product
    Choose an option:  "

  options = gets.chomp.to_i

  if options == 5
    hash.each {|key, value|
      puts "#{key} - #{value[0]}, #{value[1]}"
    }
    sorted = hash.sort_by {|product| product[1]}
    puts
    puts "The cheapest product is #{sorted.first}"
    puts "The most expensive product is #{sorted.last}"
  end
end
```

Comment: It happens because `sort_by` passes an array into the block, like this [341, ["CANDY", 3.99]]. You should use `hash.sort_by {|product| product[1][1]}`

Comment: You'd better show us the value of `hash` (not that text blob without showing us the code that turns it into `hash`) and exactly what result you want. Right now the structure and types are unclear.

Comment: added all the code so everyone can better understand whats going on with what I'm asking.

Comment: I don't believe you that that puts out 1.89 for the max. `e` is larger than `P`.

Comment: `puts "The cheapest product is #{sorted.first}"
 puts "The most expensive product is #{sorted.max.last}` is the code that was making 1.89 the max

Comment: @Victor thank you that actually fixed my issue's with some help from other answers as well, and its displaying right now with low and high

Answer (score 1):

`min` and `max` search for the minimum and maximum element in an array and return it. They are searching for the min and max using some other criteria that give the wrong result (lexicographic ordering).

But your hash's entries are already sorted correctly in the `sorted` array, so just get the first and last elements:

```
puts "The cheapest product is #{sorted[0].first}"
puts "The most expensive product is #{sorted[-1].last }"
```

Comment: Sorry i don't know why i put them in order there actually not in order. so if i try this way it brings back they key value for the cheap and then brings back the expensive = energy drink at 4.00 which its not that its the pizza at 12.99

Comment: I'm willing to bet your prices are stored as strings, so "4.00">"12.99". The quick, hacky way to fix that is to sort by `product[1].to_f`

Comment: updated the post with entire code. so its better to understand now

Answer (score 1):

No really sure whats going on, but your code doesn't work for me. Are you trying to do something like this:

```
options = {
    POP: 1.89,
    CANDY: 3.99,
    PIZZA: 12.99,
    energy_drink: 4.00
}

options.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} - #{value}, #{value}"
end

sorted = options.sort
puts
puts "The cheapest product is #{ sorted.min_by {| key, value| value } }"
puts "The most expensive product is #{ sorted.max_by {|key, value| value } }"
```

After reading your code that you posted I got it to work like this:

```
hash = {}
files = File.open("products.txt", "r")

files.each_line do |line|
  id, name, price = line.chomp.split(',')
  hash[id] = [name, price.to_f]
end

files.close

while true
  print "\n5. View highest-priced product and lowest-priced product
    Choose an option:  "

  options = gets.chomp.to_i

  if options == 5
    hash.each {|key, value|
      puts "#{key} - #{value[0]}, #{value[1]}"
    }
    sorted = hash.sort_by {|product| product[1][1]}.minmax_by { |key , value| value[1]}
    puts
    puts "The cheapest product is #{ sorted.first }"
    puts "The most expensive product is #{sorted.last}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't forget [`minmax_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by) which means you only need one call here, not two. You also don't need to sort if you're calling `min` or `max`, it doesn't help.

Comment: updated the post with entire code. so its better to understand now

Comment: @tadman Nice call I forgot about #minmax_by. That is even better.